# Read PPM Images in C

Tags: c, image-processing

Does anyone knows how can I read a PPM image into an array using C?

Thanks. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

C++ routine to read a PPM (color) image from a [file.](http://www.cs.unr.edu/~bebis/CS308/Code/RGB/ReadImage.cpp)

Comment: Sorry about this question (I do not understand nothing about C++), but I can use C++ in C?

Comment: In general, you can't. But if the C++ code uses no C++-only features it's completely valid C code.

Comment: @Smasher: So basically its C compiled with a C++ compiler?

Comment: Code will fail since PNM files use whitespace between header fields and not just \n.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [PPM reader](http://vips.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vips/vips7/trunk/libsrc/format/im_ppm2vips.c?view=markup) in C a few years ago. You're welcome to nick bits of it if you like.